# Illegal start of expression, how to correct this

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a GUI to convert decimal to binary and vice versa but
got an **illegal start of expression** on **public static void main(String args[])** .How do I correct that?

My code:

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        /**
         * Creates new form NewJFrame
         */
        public NewJFrame() {
            setTitle("Quiz");
        }

        /**
         * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
         * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
         * regenerated by the Form Editor.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
            jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            jLabel1.setText("Desimal");

            jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

            jButton1.setText("Konversikan");
            jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jTextField2.setText("jTextField2");

            jTextField3.setText("jTextField3");

            jTextField4.setText("jTextField4");

            jLabel2.setText("Biner");

            jLabel3.setText("Hexa");

            jLabel4.setText("Octal");

            jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Desimal", "Biner", "Hexa", "Octal" }));

            jTextField5.setText("jTextField5");

            jLabel5.setText("Input");

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 104, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(15, 15, 15)
                            .addComponent(jComboBox1, 0, 116, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(jButton1))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel2))
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                            .addGap(12, 12, 12)))
                                    .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 143, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addContainerGap())
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5))
                    .addGap(53, 53, 53)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                    .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4))
                    .addContainerGap(53, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        
        private void error(){
            jLabel2.setText("Input invalid");
            jLabel1.setText("Input invalid");
            jLabel3.setText("Input invalid");
            jLabel4.setText("Input invalid");
        }

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
             if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Desimal") {
                try {
                 int decimal = Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText());

                 String biner = Integer.toBinaryString(decimal);
                 String hex = Integer.toHexString(decimal);
                 String octal = Integer.toOctalString(decimal);

                 jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(decimal));
                 jTextField2.setText(biner);
                 jTextField3.setText(hex);
                 jTextField4.setText(octal);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    error();
                }
             }else if(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Biner")
             try {
                    int decimal = Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText(), 2);
                 String biner = jTextField5.getText();
                 String hex = Integer.toHexString(decimal);
                 String octal = Integer.toOctalString(decimal);

                 jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(decimal));
                 jTextField2.setText(biner);
                 jTextField3.setText(hex);
                 jTextField4.setText(octal);

                } catch (Exception e){

                }else if(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Biner")
                    try {
                int decimal = Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText(), 16);
                String biner = Integer.toBinaryString(decimal);
                String octal = Integer.toOctalString(decimal);

                jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(decimal));
                jTextField2.setText(biner);
                jTextField3.setText(jTextField5.getText());
                jTextField4.setText(octal);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }else if(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Octal"){
                try {
                int decimal = Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText(),8);

                String hexa = Integer.toHexString(decimal);
                String biner = Integer.toBinaryString(decimal);

                jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(decimal));
                jTextField2.setText(biner);
                jTextField3.setText(hexa);
                jTextField4.setText(jTextField5.getText());

                } catch (Exception e) {  
        }                                        

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
             * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
             */
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>

            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

Comment: Your code is a big mess, but most likely it is missing a closing bracket `}`.

Comment: It's good now, but the program show up as blank when i try to run it, any idea why? i already designed the gui.

Comment: Using a debugger would be very valuable right now for you.  You can step through the code and find the precise place where it is breaking.

Answer (score 2):

Fix your syntax error. You forgot the closing parenthesis for the catch block couple of lines above main method and also the closing parenthesis for the else-if above it.

Comment: Why? It is the answer

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah I don't agree. It answers the question. If there is a StackOverflow policy stating why this should be a comment, I would like to see it for my own information. In the meantime, I upvoted this.

Comment: The policy is that a simple typographical error is grounds for closing a question.  Anyway, I might answer this too on a really slow day.